# How can I use ImageDataGenerator class to generate either train and label as image for a keras model?

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, generator

I want to train a model to generate new images using Keras and I would use the ImageDataGenerator class to generate batches of images.

The problem is that I can't find a way to use this class to generate train and label batches as image. I want to pass to the model as training some images and as label some other images.

Moreover i need to do this reading each batch of images from the hard drive because the dataset is too big to load in memory.

Also an alternative to the ImageDataGenerator approach can be appreciated.

I hope the question is clear and that you can help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide more details? Maybe add some code so that we can understand what you tried so far. Even an error message can be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ImageDataGenerator` class with any type of labels you like, also images, which are just multidimensional arrays. Here is an example using dummy numpy images:

```python
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np

# Create fake images
n, width, height = 1000, 28, 28
images_data = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(n, height, width, 3))
images_labels = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(n, height, width, 3))

image_gen = ImageDataGenerator()
batch_size = 100
batch_gen = image_gen.flow(images_data, images_labels, batch_size=batch_size)
```

You can then pass `batch_gen` to `fit_generator`, for instance, and it will yield tuples of `(images_data, images_labels)`, both with shape `(batch_size, height, width, 3)`. You can check that with:

```python
batch = batch_gen.next()
print(len(batch))
print(batch[0].shape)
print(batch[1].shape)
```

If your data set does not fit in memory and is stored as files, you can also used `flow_from_directory`. There are [examples](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) in the official Keras documentation.

You can also do something to the batches before yielding them if you write your own batch generator function:

```python
def _generate_batches(image_gen, images_data, images_labels, batch_size):
    for batch in image_gen.flow(images_data, images_labels,
                                batch_size=batch_size):
        # Here you can do whatever you like to your batch
        yield (batch[0], batch[1])
```

Finally, if you need very specific functionality from your `ImageDataGenerator`, you can always build your custom `ImageDataGenerator` class:

```python
class ImageDataGeneratorCustom(ImageDataGenerator): 
...
```

In particular, you may want to overwrite the `flow()` function or even build a custom `Iterator`.

Comment: This is maybe the best approach to do what I need but it starts with the assumption that images data are loaded in memory, images_data and images_labels are numpy arrays. I need to load images reading from hard drive in batches at runtime so perhaps the @xashru answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54632769/11045375) is suitable for this part but I expected it was easier. I'm sorry but I'm a beginner with python and keras code. Thank you.

Comment: In addition if it's not clear it woud be perfect if there is something that given a path generate a batch of the images in the path. Something similar to flow_from_directory method but that give me the possibility to specify the label.

Comment: My answer addresses the title of your question "How can I use ImageDataGenerator class to generate either train and label as image for a keras model?"

The problem of the data set not fitting in memory is a different one and I'd recommend to ask one question at a time.

That said, my proposed solution does not assume the images are loaded in memory. That was for the sake of illustration and ease to copy & paste to test the code. You can use `flow_from_directory` from `ImageDataGenerator` to generate the batches directly from disk. I have edited my answer to make that explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your custom Data Generator class. This link should be helpful [data generators with Keras](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly). You can store the image labels in a large csv file and just load the required images in every batch as needed.